# Audience Network : Request but 0 impressions (admob mediation)

Tags: ios, admob, facebook-audience-network

I use `Admob` Mediation with Facebook Audience Network in our unity game to display interstitials.

On Android : all works fine
On iOS :
- If I don't add this, no facebook ads are shown. I got lots of request (with 82% of fillrate) but 0 impressions.
- If I add `[FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"xxxx"];` in `GADUInterstitial` : all works fine but I see, of course, only test ads et only on my device.

Have you any suggestion?

Comment: Is the problem that the server is reporting filled impressions (82%) but you don't receive them on the device, or that you do see the impressions on the device but no impressions are logged in your performance dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

AdSupport.framework missing in XCode.
Without this framework you can see test ads but not real ones.